# store data as xml from link in android

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I have a link from that link:

http://api.maxxiscentral.com/maxxiscentral/GetTyrePatterns

from this link i want to catch the data as string and from that string i want to create its xml file.

```
    package com.androidpeople.xml.parsing;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class XMLParsingExample extends Activity {

    /** Create Object For SiteList Class */
    SitesList sitesList = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /** Create a new layout to display the view */
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(1);

        /** Create a new textview array to display the results */
        TextView name[];
        TextView website[];
        TextView category[];

        try {

            /** Handling XML */
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
            URL sourceUrl = new URL(
                    "http://api.maxxiscentral.com/maxxiscentral/GetTyrePatterns");

            /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
            MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

        /** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
        sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

        /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
        name = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
        website = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
        category = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];

        /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
        for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {
            name[i] = new TextView(this);
            name[i].setText("Name = "+sitesList.getName().get(i));
            website[i] = new TextView(this);
            website[i].setText("Website = "+sitesList.getWebsite().get(i));
            category[i] = new TextView(this);
            category[i].setText("Website Category = "+sitesList.getCategory().get(i));

            layout.addView(name[i]);
            layout.addView(website[i]);
            layout.addView(category[i]);
        }


        /** Set the layout view to display */
        setContentView(layout);

    }
}
```

i have this code to convert string into xml but,

this code run in java but not in android. why?

and how can i get the data as from that link.

thanks in advanced.

Comment: and one more thing is that your fetching formate is totally wrong

Comment: ok than what is right, can you give me an example?

Comment: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser

Comment: in this tutorial you have to pass your url in URL sourceUrl = new URL(
"http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml");
like URL sourceUrl = new URL(
"http://api.maxxiscentral.com/maxxiscentral/GetTyrePatterns");

Comment: there are 3 class file in sax parser
as you shown in "http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser"
we have started from "sitelist.java"
in this tutorial 3 tag are desplay but in ourcase there are 15 inner tag and 3 outer tag like : 
<d:TyrePatternID> to <d:MediaID> is inner tag and <category> ,<content>,<m:properties> is outer tag.
so you have to do 
1). that how kind of datatype support this tag (like int,or string or anyone),list it out.

Comment: 2). then declare variable with get & set method
3). now jump to "MyXMLHandler.java"
4). declare your tag "localName.equals("website")" so it can match your tag and identify that get data between this
5). then after buffer those caracter in caracter method
6). now jum on "XMLParsingExample.java"
7). declare SaxParser attribute and your URL 
8). and make a procedure to call data from sitelist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [get from here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser)
>   [get it](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152) 
>   [get it](http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html) 
>   [get it](http://totheriver.com/learn/xml/xmltutorial.html) 
>   [get it](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)